# OnTextChanged triggered before writing anything

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

Im using `EditText` and trying to validate it. In my validations, Im checking if the `EditText` is empty and if it is, shows an error.

My problem is that my error is showing when the activity starts and when I didnt click anything, so is triggering before I write anything and before any text change.

What I want is to show this error If I write something and then I delete all, but not when the activity is created because will always be empty.

Any idea?

Comment: You may add a boolean flag of "DEFAULT_EMPTY = true" and in ontextchanged() change it to false when the user types something. and apply validations when it's false.

Comment: You are emptying it at startup.

Comment: Im not emptying it at startup, Im literally doing nothing with edittexts, im not setting text